# entity framework code first como usarlo con una base de datos ya existente

Tags: entity-framework-6

Buenas, tengo una base de datos que no fue creada con Entity Framework code first. Tiene tablas y datos independientes, luego, cree otro proyecto web independiente en el que si utilizo EF. Es posible utilizar la BD que ya existe para poner ahi las entidades del EF. Es decir que cuando hago los update-database NO me toque las otras tablas y relaciones?

Hago una aclaracion. Yo quiero que el entity Framework NO VEA LAS TABLAS que tengo ya creadas, solo quiero utilizar la misma instancia de BD

Answer (score 1):

Si la puedes utilizar solo mapear las clases con las tablas y agregarlas al modelo. Pero si ya estas usando migraciones de C# para generar las tablas en sql. Tendrás problemas. Por que te va intentar crear tablas que ya están en la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Si la base de datos ya fue creada, te recomendaría utilizar Database First para que te genere las entidades y el mapeo automáticamente.

Aquí podrás encontrar un poco de documentación de Database First:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database

Por otra parte,  si quieres utilizar Code First, tendrías que mapear cada una de las tablas.

Con respecto al mapping, este es manual y requiere demasiado esfuerzo ya que se tendría que hacer tabla por tabla.

A continuación un ejemplo de mapping de la tabla usuario.

```cs
public class UsuarioMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Usuario>
    {
        public UsuarioMapping()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.Id);
            Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasColumnName("id");
            Property(x => x.Nombre).HasColumnName("nombre");
            Property(x => x.ApellidoPaterno).HasColumnName("apellidoPaterno");
            Property(x => x.ApellidoMaterno).HasColumnName("apellidoMaterno");
            Property(x => x.Correo).HasColumnName("correo");
            Property(x => x.NombreUsuario).HasColumnName("usuario");
            Property(x => x.Contrasena).HasColumnName("contrasena");
            Property(x => x.Estatus).HasColumnName("estatus");
            ToTable("tblUsuarios");
        }
    }
```

El contexto sería de la siguiente manera:

```cs
public class MainContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            try
            {                
                var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                    .Where(type => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
                    .Where(type => type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.IsGenericType
                    && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));
                foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
                {                    
                    dynamic configurationInstancie = Activator.CreateInstance(type);                    
                    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstancie);                    
                }

                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //handle
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: perdon, no se si me exprese bien, la idea es NO tocar las tablas que ya existen. Es decir, que el EF no se entere, no me las borre o no me cambie los datos que ya existen, pero que pueda utilizar la conexion a la bd.